# Session expires on windows azure server

Tags: session, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, session-state, session-timeout

I have stored some data in Session. When i try to access this data on different view files (*.cshtml), it works fine on localhost. But when I deploy it on "windowsazure.com", it results:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Line 14:     string imageurl = Session["imageurl"].ToString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fahad

This anwser is based on the assupmtion that you have moore than one instance of your web role running.

windows Azure uses load balencing based on a round robbin princeple. It also doenot support sticky sessions. The result is that the first en second requrest to your web site are, in general, processed on 2 differnt servers. This explains the empty state.
You can configure your deployment to use shared memory and use the Azure cashing pattern to solve this problem.

This patren is expliand in de windows Azure Training Kit.

Michiel

Comment: Thanks Michiel.
How to configure deployment to use shared memory and use the Azure caching?
In windows azure websites management (https://manage.windowsazure.com) section,  I could not find any option for such configuration.

Comment: Michiel

I changed mode of session to SQLServer, and gave a Connection String web.config.


<sessionState timeout="7200" mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Server=*.database.windows.net,1433;Database=ASPState;User ID=username;Password=pwd;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
                   allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" cookieless="false"></sessionState>

Problem solved using this approach.
Thanks for guiding me about session state in windows azure.